# failed to find nested object under path

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have mappings:

```
"mappings": {
  "productsearchmodel": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "properties": {
        "properties": {
          "invariant": {
            "properties": {
              "Name": {
                "analyzer": "Replace",
                "boost": 40,
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Description": {
                "analyzer": "Replace",
                "boost": 40,
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "type": "nested"
          },
        },
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
```

my query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "properties.invariant",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "Bal",
                "fields": [
                  "Description"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but result is:

```
{
"took": 5,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 2,
"successful": 1,
"failed": 1,
"failures": [
{
"index": "pagesearchmodel",
"shard": 0,
"status": 400,
"reason": "RemoteTransportException[[Powerpax][inet[/192.168.0.57:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[pagesearchmodel][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"path":"properties.invariant","query":{"query_string":{"query":"Bal","fields":["Description"]}}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[pagesearchmodel] [nested] failed to find nested object under path [properties.invariant]]; "
}
]
},
"hits": {
"total": 0,
"max_score": null,
"hits": [ ]
}
}
```

Comment: Are you you pasted the mapping correctly? That is not valid JSON.

Comment: might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29346935/2529583

Answer (score 2):

I didn't specify an index in my request url and search tried to perfom on all indexex which have different structures.