# Can I ignore "failed to find nested object under path" in ElasticSearch if I get results?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an index with mapping that includes nested fields. In our Java class these fields are lists of objects, and sometimes the lists can be empty (so in the json structure we get e.g {... "some_nested_field": [], ...}.
When we run a query we do get results as expected, but also an error:

```
"failures": [
  {
    "shard": 0,
    "index": ".kibana",
    "node": "ZoEuUdkORpuBSNs7gqiv1Q",
    "reason": {
      "type": "query_shard_exception",
      "reason": """
failed to create query: {
  "nested" : {
"query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "foobar.name" : {
            "query" : "brlo",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
},
"path" : "foobar",
"ignore_unmapped" : false,
"score_mode" : "avg",
"boost" : 1.0
  }
}
""",
      "index_uuid": "xrFCunLNSv6AER_KwNMHSA",
      "index": ".kibana",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [foobar]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Can I assume that this error is caused by records with empty lists, and ignore it? Or does this indicate an internal error and possibly missing results from my query? Is there a way to avoid this error?

### UPDATE:

This is an example of the query we're executing:

```
GET /_search
{
"query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "mynested",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should" : [
                        { "match" : { "mynested.name": "foo" } },
                        { "match" : { "mynested.description": "bar" } },
                    { "match" : { "mynested.category": "baz" } }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The response from ES reports 10 successful shards and one failure:

```
{
  "took": 889,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 11,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [...]
```

And we do get hits back:

```
  "hits": {
      "total": 234450,
      "max_score": 11.092936,
      "hits": [ ...
```

Comment: This error message means that you tried to execute a `nested` query on a field that is not `nested`. Check out this SO question because it is related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346935/elasticsearch-nested-object-under-path-is-not-of-nested-type

Comment: Thanks @NikolayVasiliev, but my field is definitely nested and I DO in fact get results from the query (which wouldn't be the case if the field was not nested). That's why I suspect the error is caused by empty-list values in this field and not from my configuration. Just trying to verify this...

Comment: May you please also post the request you make? With url and http method.

Comment: Hi @NikolayVasiliev, I edited my question and added the info you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have Kibana installed. In the error message it says that it can't find `nested` under path `foobar` of index `.kibana`, which is the one that Kibana uses:

```
  "index_uuid": "xrFCunLNSv6AER_KwNMHSA",
  "index": ".kibana",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [foobar]"
  }
```

When doing simple `GET /_search` *all* Elasticsearch indexes are queried, also `.kibana`, which is probably not what you wanted.

To ignore this particular index you can use [Multiple Indices search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/multi-index.html) capability and do a query like:

```
GET /*,-.kibana/_search
```

Hope that helps!